# In a right triangle, if you know angle between hypotenuse / side, how do you tell apart between adjacent/opposite?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

So cos(78.75°) = adjacent/hypotenuse

which is the hypotenuse here? The longest side? Is it 1 then? What's the adjacent for the angle 78.75°? Is it 1 or 2?

Comment: hypotenuse is always opposite the right angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite side to the angle with degree 78.75 is side 3, and the adjacent side is side 2. The opposite side is the side that does not touch the angle. The adjacent side is the side that touches the angle but is not the hypotenuse. The hypotenuse in any triangle is the longest side (side 1), and it is always the side that does not touch the right angle.